# Facebook graph API prevents from accessing data due to non active account - Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, account

I am using Graph API of Facebook in Android Studio to pull status from a public facebook page but Graph Request kept responding in a Null Pointer Exception.
Debugging led to this message that 'Access to this data is temporarily disabled for non-active accounts due to changes we are making to the Facebook Platform'.

```
 AccessToken token= new AccessToken(getString(R.string.accessToken),
            getString(R.string.facebook_app_id),
            getString(R.string.userID),null,null,null,null,null );
            GraphRequest req= GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(token, "453355835083862",
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    Log.e("Error","Error in response: " + error.getErrorMessage());

                    Log.e("Output", response.getJSONObject().toString());
                }
            });
    GraphRequest.executeBatchAsync(req);
```

which gives output:

> 03-25 15:48:49.867 17225-17225/com.example.daroodar.qbwirelessapp
>   E/Error: Error in response:  (#200) Access to this data is temporarily
>   disabled for non-active accounts due to changes we are making to the
>   Facebook Platform

What does this mean?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/205942813488872/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your application is not active now. Check application status in [FB developers console](https://developers.facebook.com). Possible you'll need to start new app review (check App review tab in [FB console](https://developers.facebook.com)).

Also check if your application permissions are allowed by  [FB Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).